# React native axios api calls with redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, axios, redux-thunk

I'm struggling to get a basic api call setup with redux and axios in React Native.

This is my reducer index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import LibaryReducer from './LibraryReducer'
import ImportLibraryReducer from './ImportLibraryReducer'

let defaultState = {
    card: null
}


const mainReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
    if(action.type === "CHANGE_CARDS") {
        return {
            ...state,
            card: action.card
        }
    } else {
       return {
        ...state
       }
    }
}

export default mainReducer
```

This is my action index.js

```
import axios from "axios"

export function loadCards(){
    return(dispatch)=>{
        return axios.get('http://localhost:4000/reports')
                .then(response => {
                    dispatch(changeCards(response.data))
                })
    }
}

export function changeCards(cards) {
    return{
        type: "CHANGE_CARDS",
        card: card
    }
}
```

This is my app.js

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 */

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import MainPage from './components/MainPage'
import { Header } from "native-base"

import Card from './components/Card'

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

import reducers from './reducers'

const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk))

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <View>
          <Header ><Text>hello</Text></Header>
          <Card />
        </View>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

And, finally, this is where I'm trying to retrieve the data from the api call:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {Collapse,CollapseHeader, CollapseBody, AccordionList} from 'accordion-collapse-react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as actions from '../actions'

class Card extends Component {



  render() {

    const titleStyle = {
      backgroundColor: '#edeeef',
      fontWeight: "bold",
      color: '#454647',
      fontSize: 16,
      left: 8,
      fontFamily: 'Ionicons',
      top: 10
    }

    const descMarkStyle = {
      left: 8,
      top: 4,
      fontFamily: 'Ionicons',
      color: '#454647',
      fontSize: 16
    }

    console.log('in the render', this.props)

    return (
      <View>
          <Collapse >
              <CollapseHeader>
                <View
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: '#edeeef',
                    height: 38,
                    postion: 'absolute',
                    borderBottomWidth: .5,
                    borderBottomColor: '#black'
                  }} 
                >
                  <Text style={titleStyle}>
                   test
                  </Text>
                </View>

              </CollapseHeader>
              <CollapseBody>
                <Text style={descMarkStyle}>test</Text>
                <Text style={descMarkStyle}>test</Text>
              </CollapseBody>
            </Collapse>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    state
   };
 }

 export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Card);
```

When I try to console log this.props in the component above, I get the default state of card: null without the api running: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWtmF.jpg

I'm new to redux, and I feel like there is something obvious that I'm missing.

Comment: It doesn't appear that you're calling your action anywhere.

Comment: Where should I be calling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should trigger your action in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method in your `Card` component. Also, you can destructure your actions in your imports and in your `connect`.

```
import { loadCards } from '../actions'

class Card extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
  this.props.loadCards()
}
```

And in `connect`:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { loadCards })(Card);
```

Also in the `changeCards` action:

```
card: cards
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how to set up axios with redux hooks and react-native in 4 steps:**

*source code: https://github.com/trackmystories/Redux-hooks-counter-app-with-axios.*

**Step 1:**

create an actions.js file:

*actions.js*

```html
export const TOTAL_COUNT = "TOTAL_COUNT";

export const totalCount = (data) => ({
  type: TOTAL_COUNT,
  data,
});
```

**Step 2:**

define and combine your reducers:

reducer.js

```html
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import { TOTAL_COUNT } from "./actions";

let dataState = { data: [] };

const total_counts = (state = dataState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOTAL_COUNT:
      return { ...state, data: action.data };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const counter = (state = 0, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD":
      return state + 1;
    case "SUBTRACT":
      return state - 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  counter,
  total_counts,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**Step 3**

create an axios get request and put request as defined in the example below and dispatch and get data.

With hooks you don't need to use connect mapStateToProps and dispatchStateToProps with redux hooks instead use { useDispatch, useSelector }.

We can pass the actions "ADD" and "SUBTRACT" inside of the button directly, without defining an action.js file.

CounterComponent.js

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import ActionButton from "./ActionButton";
import SubmitButton from "./SubmitButton";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import axios from "axios";
import { totalCount } from "../actions";

export default function CounterComponent() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);

  const total_counts = useSelector((state) => state.total_counts);
  const counter = useSelector((state) => state.counter);

  const { data } = total_counts;

  useEffect(() => getTotalCount(), []);

  const getTotalCount = () => {
    setIsFetching(true);

    let url = "https://url.firebaseio.com<name>.json";
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then((res) => res.data)
      .then((data) => dispatch(totalCount(data)))
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message))
      .finally(() => setIsFetching(false));
  };

  const onSubmit = (counterState) => {
    let url = "https://url.firebaseio.com<name>.json";
    axios.put(url, counterState).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  };

  return (
    <View>

          <ActionButton
            onPress={() =>
              dispatch({
                type: "SUBTRACT",
              })
            }
            title="subtract"
          />
         
   
       <View>  
        {isFetching ? (
          <ActivityIndicator />
        ) : (
          <View>
            <Text>
              Current state:
              {data.counter ? data.counter : counter}
            </Text>
          </View>
        )}
       </View>

          <ActionButton
            onPress={() =>
              dispatch({
                type: "ADD",
              })
            }
            title="add"
          />

      
      <SubmitButton
        onPress={onSubmit({
          counterState: counter,
        })}
        title="Submit"
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

**Step 4:**

Lastly link your RootReducer to the createStore and pass it to the Provider.

```html
import React from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import CounterComponent from "./src/components/CounterComponent";
import rootReducer from "./src/reducer";

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Counter example with Redux Hooks and Axios</Text>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <CounterComponent />
      </Provider>
    </View>
  );
}
```